# Zend Framework 2 & Apigility - insert link into collection

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I have an Apigility resource with a `patchList` method.
The method returns a collection.
I need to set a link to another resource on the returned collection.

So, if a collection looks like this:

```
{
  _links: {
    self: '//foo.bar',
  },
  _embedded: {
    foo: []
  }    
}
```

I want it to be like so:

```
{
  _links: {
    self: '//foo.bar',
    bar: '//foo.bar/456'
  },
  _embedded: {
    foo: []
  }    
}
```

Now, I have read [the docs](https://apigility.org/documentation/modules/zf-hal), and I see how I can add a static link, but I need the link to be set dynamically.
I think I might be able to achieve this by listening to the `renderCollection` event, but I was wondering if there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single resources you can also use the `EntityExtractor` to add custom links to the `LinkCollection`, but for rendering a `Collection` such an extractor is not used so all you can do to add them dyamically is by using the `renderCollection` event like you already suggested in your question.